# How to get the documents for which the value is present in an array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
_id:"1",
"project_id":"1",
"Name":"A",
"type":{
 "user":[a,b,c]
}
}

{
_id:"2",
"Name":"A",
"project_id":"2",
"type":{
 "user":[b]
}
}

{
_id:"3",
"Name":"A",
"project_id":"1",
"type":{
 "user":[a]
}
}

{
 _id:"4",
"Name":"A",
"project_id":"3",
"type":{
 "user":[a,b,c]
}
}
```

Above is the collection "Project" where it has a embedded document called "type" which has an array "user"
i want to write  a mongodb query which gets me the documents for the "project_id":"1" and for the value "a" in "user" array

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({ "project_id":"1",
  "type.user": "a"
})
```

check this [mongoplayground result example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8VGEZk8KXlg) 
I invite you to read [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for single user with single **project_id**, let say **user a**:

```
db.projects.find({"project_id": "1", "type.user": "a"});
```

Or, If in near future, you want to search for multiple users with single **project_id**, let say **user a & b**:

```
db.projects.find({"project_id": "1", "type.user": { $in: ["a", "b"] } });
```

Hope it helps to you!